# How can I disable the 'e' PREG_REPLACE_EVAL modifier in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, security

I want to know how to disable the eval modifier in PHP's regex system eg. `preg_replace('/.*/e', $code, '.')`. It's a potential exploit that can be used in place of eval if anyone manages to get dodgy code onto a server. I had a problem recently with a wordpress theme from woothemes that had a security hole that allowed hackers to upload a back door server admin type script.

I have this in my php.ini:

```
disable_functions = eval
```

Which prevented most of the damage that could've been done but I was wondering if I can do something similar to prevent all forms of 'eval' apart from the `call_user_func_array()` stuff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Suhosin extension](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin.127.html) provides an option to [disable the `/e` modifier](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier).

`disable_functions = eval` by the way won't do what you expect (as `eval` is not a function, but a language construct). Again the Suhosin extension provides an option to [disable `eval`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.executor.disable_eval).

Answer (score 2):

find & replace ? :)

No you cannot disable a specific functionality of a specific function.

What you can do however, is to keep your server updated & protected. You may try to run the apache process within a chroot, limit the used resources, install a firewall, etc... you can find lots of tutorials on how to secure your linux installation on the net.

I found these related to wordpress, seems like a  bunch of sane tips:

- http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/security/20-steps-to-a-flexible-and-secure-wordpress-installation/
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: Cheers. It wasn't so much the apache or server setup in general but the particular theme a client was using that had the security hole. If it can't be turned off then there's not much to do bar patching the theme.

Comment: try to keep all installed software updated. All software contains some kind of bugs, in one way or another... if you want some kind of really secure environment, look at chroot, or some kind of virtualization technology, to keep your real server separate from the client's software

Answer (score 2):

To remove the modifier "e" from regular expressions (for example, if the user has access to setting regular expressions in applications), I wrote a function to cut out the modifier "e" from any regexp pattern.

```
function remove_emodifier($pattern)
{
    $pattern_parts = explode($pattern{0}, trim($pattern));
    $pattern_last = sizeof($pattern_parts) - 1;
    $pattern_parts[$pattern_last] = str_replace('e', '', $pattern_parts[$pattern_last]);

    return implode($pattern{0}, $pattern_parts);
}

echo preg_replace('/^(.*)$/iex', 'strrev("\\1")', 'my_string'); // gnirts_ym
echo preg_replace(remove_emodifier('/^(.*)$/iex'), 'strrev("\\1")', 'my_string'); // strrev("my_string")

echo remove_emodifier('|abc|eix'); // |abc|ix
echo remove_emodifier('#.+(\d+)#iseU'); // #.+(\d+)#isU
```

Answer (score 0):

The Diseval PHP extension will also disable the /e modifier in both php5 and php7 while at the same time disabling eval:
https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_diseval_extension